# #2014 Command of sync when running a query on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I have a categories table which has (id,name,parent_categ)
I want to select the category with its children categories (the root category parent is null)

and that is my query :

```
SELECT M.`id`, M.`name`,(select S.`name` from `categories` AS S where M.`id` = S.`parent_categ` ) AS sub
FROM `categories` AS M
Group by M.`id`,M.`name`
```

why giving me that error?!!

## 2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: It's not really the mysql query that matters for this error, but the way you tried to execute it and the previous ones from your code. So, pls paste your application code as well. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT M.`id`, M.`name`, sub.`name` 
FROM 
    (select S.`name` from `categories` AS S) AS sub, 
    `categories` AS M 
WHERE 
    M.`id` = sub.`parent_categ`
GROUP BY
    M.`id`,M.`name`
```